# I wanna console.log the value after clicking the submit button once and to delete the previous mapped items, but it doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, onclick, mapping, onsubmit

I'm very new to react and I got two problems:

1. I want to `console log` the input and display the mapped data after clicking the submit button once. But I get console logged the input and the mapped data after clicking the button twice.
2. I wanna *clear* the mapped list (data from previous input) and display new list items depending on the input. But the new list items are only added to the end of the previous list (only the last list item from the previous list got overwritten by the first list item of the new list).

So this is the code from my app component:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Display from './/Display';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: "",
      passedValue: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    this.setState({ passedValue: this.state.value });
    console.log(this.state.passedValue);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form className="inputContainer" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" name="company_name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <Display listDataFromParent={this.state.passedValue} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And this is my display component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import "./Display.css";

export default class Display extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/company?company_name=" + this.props.listDataFromParent)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            data: result
          });
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }
  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, data } = this.state;
    // if (error) {
    //   return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    // } else if (!isLoaded) {
    //   return <div>Loading...</div>;
    // } else {
    return (
      <div className="display">
        <h1>Kreditnehmer</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.props.listDataFromParent}

          {data.map(item => (
            <li key={item.c.company_id}>
              Relation type: {item.r.relation_group}
              Last name: {item.p.last_name}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Answers are:

1) Callback function should be used on `setState`, in order to do `console.log` after state is really updated.

In your case you call `setState` and `setState` is **async** function, which means that `console.log` won't wait until state is really updated.

Your code should be:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    this.setState({ passedValue: this.state.value }, 
                  () => console.log(this.state.passedValue));
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

2) I would move data fetching out of `componentWillReceiveProps()`, since this lifecycle method will be deprecated from version 17 and it is fired on every `render()`.  Try replacing with `componentDidMount()` or `componentDidUpdate()`. Maybe just this small change will solve your problem. If not pls post results and I will take a look again.

Answer (score 0):

1) `setState` is `async` method in react means it will take some time to update the component state. You can get your console log by using callback function of setState like

```
this.setstate({ value: e.target.value }, ()  => {  console.log(this.state.value) });
```

2) in display component, your using componentWillReciveProps life cycle and inside that your using `this.props.listdatafromparent` which is pointing previous props. Rather than using `this.props` I would suggest consider `props` param of life cycle, means it should be like

```
componentWillReciveProps(props) {
// your code
Console.log(props.listdatafromparent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The handleSubmit method is wrong... the console log is executed before the state is changed. You need to put it inside a callback function as a second parameter of setState.

```
this.setState({ passedValue: this.state.value }, () => {
console.log(this.state.passedValue);
```

});